# Generating fibonacci words in c++

Tags: c++

I might sound stupid but wanted to ask how to generate a Fibonacci "word" series in c++.

Example:- `f(0) = "a", f(1) = "b", f(2) = "ba", f(3) = "bab", upto order n.`

Do I need to append recursively?

Comment: Recursion is _one way_ to solve a fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Show your code. Preferably as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

It can easily be done with recursion using c++'s `std::string`:

```
std::string wordFib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return "a";
    if (n == 1) return "b";
    return wordFib(n - 1) + wordFib(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I need to perform the same function but without using recursion, do you know how to do it without using recursion, please?